# How to use global-module class for ejb home/remote?

Tags: java, maven, ejb, wildfly, maven-3

Migrating an existing project to maven and wildfly and had to move some files around creating the following situation.

- core.jar
- ejb1.jar
- ejb2.jar

With the ejb-jar.xml for ejb1.jar having the following:

```
<ejb-jar>
  <enterprise-beans>
    <session id="Value">
      ..
      <home>path.to.ejb1Home</home>
      <remote>path.to.ejb1</remote>
      ...
```

The classes referenced in the home and remote tags have moved to be inside core.jar

Meanwhile ejb2.jar has dependencies on other parts of core.jar.

What looked like the easiest resolution was to create a global module and place core.jar in it, creating the appropriate module.xml and entry in standalone.sh to make it accessible to all deployments.

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="path.to"> 
  <resources> 
    <resource-root path="core-1.0.jar"/>
  </resources> 
  <dependencies> 
  </dependencies> 
</module>
```

With this setup, ejb2.jar deploys as expected but ejb1.jar throws the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link path.to.ejb1 
    (Module "path.to" from local module loader @4c40b76e (finder: local 
     module finder @2ea6137 (roots: /opt/wildfly/modules, 
     /opt/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base))): javax/ejb/EJBObject
```

Comment: What do you mean with "creating ... an entry in standalone.sh" ?

Comment: Typo, meant standalone.xml to indicate it to the server as a global module on boot.

Comment: How are you deploying the application, are you using an EAR? Are you talking about EJB2? Which version of Wildfly?

Comment: Ideally the goal is to deploy one ejb per ear, should be EJB3, Wildfly 14

Answer (score 0):

You should carefully think about your requirement. Usually, you don't need to provide common resources, especially application interfaces, as module, especially as global module. Choose the right solution for your requirements, not a solutions that looks easy at first sight without knowing the implications.

I would recommend these possibilities in the order given (see the [Class Loading in Wildfly Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Class+Loading+in+WildFly) for more information):

1. Reconsider your requirement for different EARs. Provide the core jar as library with your EAR.
2. Even with more than one EAR: provide the core.jar as library. This is no redundancy, this is just separation.
3. Consider not using a global module. Just install your custom module. Provide a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file, adding this module as additional dependency. If the module contains annotated classes or interfaces, which should be considered upon deployment, set the attribute `annotations=true` with the module dependency configuration.
4. Add a global module to your configuration file. Probably you can even use the `annotations'  property, but this is something I don't know and I didn't check.

An example for the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file:

```
    <jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.3">
      <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
      <deployment>
        <dependencies>
          <module name="my.custom.module" export="true" annotations="true"/>
        </dependencies>
      </deployment>
    </jboss-deployment-structure>
```

**EDIT:**

When installing modules, don't forget to provide transitive module dependencies to other modules your own module depends on. User your `module.xml` file to do so. In your case, you probably need at least a dependency to the `javax.ejb.api` module.